# Haskell: Deriving Show for custom type

Tags: haskell, show, typeclass, ghci

I have this type definition:

```
data Operace = Op (Int->Int->Int) String (Int->Int->Int) deriving Show
```

I want to print this type into the interactive shell (GHCi). All that should be printed is the `String` field.

I tried this:

```
instance Show Operace where
    show (Op op str inv) = show str
```

But I still keep getting

```
No instance for (Show (Int -> Int -> Int))
  arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Show (Int -> Int -> Int))
  or use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
       so you can specify the instance context yourself
When deriving the instance for (Show Operace)
```

I don't want to add `Show` for `(Int->Int->Int)`, all I want to print is the string.

Thanks for help!

**EDIT:**

For future reference, the fixed version is:

```
data Operace = Op (Int->Int->Int) String (Int->Int->Int)

instance Show Operace where
    show (Op _ str _) = str
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The instance declaration you made is the correct way to go. It seems you forgot to remove that faulty `deriving` clause from the original `data` declaration.

```
data Operace = Op (Int->Int->Int) String (Int->Int->Int)

instance Show Operace where
   show (Op op str inv) = show str
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks. I expected it would work like in C-like languages, where you declare list of parent types in class definition.

Comment: @mzabsky: This is a powerful mechanism, as you can define additional type class instances for an existing type without touching its definition.

Answer (score 30):

You can derive `Show`, just import `Text.Show.Functions` first.