# Haskell Deriving Show Instance

Tags: haskell, show, deriving

I am playing with a Red-Black tree:

```
-- Taken from Okasaki 1999
module RedBlackTree where

--node coloring data
--a node is R (red) or B (black)
data Color = R | B

--tree constructor
--a RBT can be E (empty) or be T (a non empty tree)
data RBT e = E | T Color (RBT e) e (RBT e)

--set operations on tree
type Set a = RBT a

--define an empty set
empty :: Set e
empty = E

--define a member of a set
--Sees if an item of type e is
--in a set if type e elements
member :: (Ord e) => e -> Set e -> Bool
member x E = False
member x (T _ a y b) | x <  y = member x a -- if less, go left
                     | x == y = True
                     | x >  y = member x b -- if more, go right


--tree operations
--Insert an element
insert :: (Ord e) => e -> Set e -> Set e
insert x s = makeBlack (ins s)
    where ins E = T R E x E --basically the typical BST insert
          ins (T color a y b) | x <  y = balance color (ins a) y b
                              | x == y = T color a y b
                              | x >  y = balance color a y (ins b)
          makeBlack (T _ a y b) = T B a y b --inserts a black node

-- balance operations
--case 1:
balance B (T R (T R a x b) y c) z d = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
--case 2:
balance B (T R a x (T R b y c)) z d = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
--case 3:
balance B a x (T R (T R b y c) z d) = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
--case 4:
balance B a x (T R b y (T R c z d)) = T R (T B a x b) y (T B c z d)
--generic balancing operation
balance color a x b = T color a x b
```

If I execute the following statement in GHCi:

```
> RedBlackTree.insert ('b') (RedBlackTree.T R E ('a') E)
```

The following error message tells me there is not an instance of show for `Set Char`:

```
<interactive>:116:1:
No instance for (Show (Set Char)) arising from a use of `print'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (Set Char))
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I know the tree is working because by calling `member 'b' ...` where `...` is the previously executed statement, the returned value is `True`. I've been reading the other SO posts on this problem but the solutions found for them (e.g.:[Haskell: Deriving Show for custom type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082090/haskell-deriving-show-for-custom-type)) does not work.

For example, by adding:

```
instance Show Set where:
    show (Set Char) = show Char
```

I get the following error message when I try to load using `:l`:

> :l red-black-tree.hs
>       [1 of 1] Compiling RedBlackTree     ( red-black-tree.hs, interpreted )

```
red-black-tree.hs:54:11: Not in scope: data constructor `Set'

red-black-tree.hs:54:15: Not in scope: data constructor `Char'

red-black-tree.hs:54:28: Not in scope: data constructor `Char'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I think there are a few problems going on with what I'm trying to do but I can't seem to figure it out from the available documentation.

Comment: Just use `data Tree a = ... deriving (Show)`

Comment: Appending `deriving (Show)` to the end of `data RBT...` gives me the following error message:  `No instance for (Show Color)
      arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration`

Comment: Just add `deriving (Show)` to the end of `data Color = R | B`

Answer (score 5):

To transform a value into a string, Haskell uses a so-called type class. Simplified, type classes just provide functions that behave differently depending on the type of their argument. This approach is very similar to method overloading known from object-oriented programming languages. The type class `Show` provides a function called `show` that transforms a value of some type into a string. For example, the expression `show 1` yields the string `"1"`. If there is a function `show` that transforms a value of some type into a string we say that there is an instance of the type class `Show` for this type. In other words, there is an instance of the type class `Show` for integers.

This `show` function is also used when you evaluate an expression in ghci. Therefore, it tells you that there is no instance `(Show (Set Char))`, in other words, it does not know, how to transform a value of type `Set Char` into a string. For custom types like your types `Set`, `RBT`, and `Color` you have to provide instances of the type class `Show` in order to display values of theses types on the console. To define an instance of the type class `Show` for the type `Color` you can use the following definition.

```
instance Show Color where:
  show R = "Red"
  show B = "Black"
```

That is, if you write `R` into ghci, it will print `Red`. For simple Haskell data types, there is a canonical definition of the `Show` type class. For example, the canonical definition of `Show` for `Color` is as follows.

```
instance Show Color where:
  show R = "R"
  show B = "B"
```

To relieve the user from defining instances like this, Haskell provides a so-called "deriving mechanism". That is, if you write

```
  deriving (Show)
```

after the definition of a data type, the compiler will generate a canonical instance of the `Show` type class for your data type.

If a data type makes use of another data type, deriving a `Show` instance of the former will require a `Show` instance of the latter. For example, consider the following data type.

```
data RBT e = E | T Color (RBT e) e (RBT e)
```

The data type `RBT` uses the type `Color` in its definition. The canonical `Show` instance of the `T` constructor will start with "T " and afterwards show the value of type `Color`. Therefore, deriving the `Show` instance for `RBT` requires an instance of `Show` for `Color`.

Answer (score 4):

Your instance code is broken:

```
instance Show Set where
    show (Set Char) = show Char
```

1. The compiler complains that `Set` is not a data constructor, and it isn't - it's a type synonym name. So you incorrectly used `Set` in a pattern. You can use data constructors there - and for `RBT` data constructors are `T` and `E`.
2. Your instance declaration is ill-kinded: `Set` is a synonym for `RBT` and `RBT` has one type argument, that is it's a function from type to type, with a kind signature of `* -> *`. But `Show` instance requires a type without an argument, that is a type and not a type constructor, kind `*` instead of `* -> *` you supplied. So you should fix that by supplying either `instance Show (RBT Char)` or `instance (Show a) => RBT a`.

What you probably wanted is to write "show a set of char by showing chars inside of it".

So to fix your instance:

```
instance Show (RBT Char) where
    show a = "something"
```

But it doesn't show anything useful. You need to do pattern matching on constructors of RBT to get the work done:

```
instance Show (RBT Char) where
    show E = "something"
    show (T a b c d) = "something else"
```

But for your task it will be simpler just to use the derived `Show` instances for `RBT a` and `Color`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any fancy extensions in use, so you should be able to use the built-in `deriving` mechanism for `Show`.

In order for it to automatically derive a `Show` instance for a data type, all of the types used in your type definition must also have `Show` instances. Just add `deriving (Show)` to the end of *all* of your `data` definitions. You may want to just get in the habit of adding `deriving (Eq, Show)` to all your `data` types, since you'll almost always want structural equality tests and showability for your types.

Also, you cannot make a class instance of any sort for a *type alias*, only for a *type*. The keyword `type` defines a type alias, not a new type. If you make a `Show` instance for your `RBT a` type, it will automatically be used for anything you declare as a `Set a`, since `Set a` is just an alias for `RBT a`.