# How to instantiate the Show class after definition of the data structure

Tags: haskell

I want to derive a `Show` instance for a data structure which is very simple:

```
data MySQLConnectInfo = MySQLConnectInfo
    { mysqlHost       :: String
    , mysqlUser       :: String
    , mysqlPassword   :: String
    , mysqlDatabase   :: String
    , mysqlPort       :: Int
    , mysqlUnixSocket :: String
    , mysqlGroup      :: Maybe String
    }
```

I do not wish to modify the library's code manually. Is it possible to automatically derive a `Show` instance well after the definition (in another module) as one would create it when adding a `deriving` clause after the `data` definition?
I tried to leave a `instance Show MySQLConnectInfo` but the compiler complains that there is no definition of `show` or `showPrec`. It is a pain to manually write an instance of `Show`, is there a better, automagical way (possibly using GHC extensions)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haskell: Deriving Show for custom type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082090/haskell-deriving-show-for-custom-type)

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Should I remove this one?